# Spacing between "label" and "input" in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

Is it possible to reduce the spacing between `label` and `input`?

[image]

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12" >
    <div class="card mb-1"  style="background-color:aqua;">
      <div class="card-body" >
         <div class="row " >
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4" >
               <div class="form-group  d-flex" >
                  <label for="name" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Title</label>
                   <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                       <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control"
                            style="background-color: white; max-width: 300px;width: 100%;"
                            placeholder="myInput" autofocus>
                      </div>
               </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My solution is to use of the CSS ? Can i do it ? I created a class `moveInput`

```
...
<label for="name" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Title</label>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 moveInput">
...
```

With the following properties:

```
.moveInput {
  position: relative;
  left: -180px;
}
```

It work ! But, if you have another solution in Bootsrtrap, I am interested.

Thank you

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">  
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12" >
      <div class="card mb-1"  style="background-color:aqua;">
         <div class="card-body" >
            <div class="row " >
              <div class="col-12 col-lg-4" >
                 <div class="form-group  d-flex" >
                    <label for="name" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Title</label>
                      <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control"
                        style="background-color: white; max-width: 300px;width: 100%;"
                        placeholder="myInput" autofocus>
                      </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want both of them in center or at left side

Comment: @ Navnath Jadhav: At left, please... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<label for="name" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Title</label>`

to

`<label for="name" class="col-2 col-sm-1 col-form-label">Title</label>`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">  
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12" >
      <div class="card mb-1"  style="background-color:aqua;">
         <div class="card-body" >
            <div class="row " >
              <div class="col-12 col-lg-4" >
                 <div class="form-group  d-flex" >
                    <label for="name" class="col-2 col-sm-1 col-form-label">Title</label>
                      <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control"
                        style="background-color: white; max-width: 300px;width: 100%;"
                        placeholder="myInput" autofocus>
                      </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Navnath Jadhav it's ok !